# Преобразование doc в pdf на сайте

Tags: pdf, php, doc

Здравствуйте! Как можно сделать, чтобы *.doc файлы, загруженные зарегистрированными пользователями на сервер, отображались в браузере? Как сконвертировать DOC в PDF на сервере? Google Documents не предлагать.

Comment: А какая система? linux -- м.б.

      libreoffice --nologo --invisible --convert-to pdf file.doc

или что-нибудь похожее. Сам не делал.

Answer (score 5):

То, что вам нужно:

1. О том как парсить DOC в [статье на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/72745/) и сам [парсер DOC-файлов на гитхабе](https://github.com/rembish/TextAtAnyCost).
2. [Пример генерации в PDF на сервере](http://ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-buildpdfphp/).
3. [Использующаяся в примере библиотека](http://www.fpdf.org/).
4. [Коммерческая версия библиотеки](http://www.pdflib.com/).

---

Comment: А теперь дополните список набором ссылок для разбора .doc-файлов...

Comment: дополнил, спасибо

Comment: Тут недавно давали ссылку на один сайт (в вопросе об интересных ресурсах), там есть статья на близкую тему http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B_Microsoft_Office_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%3F_%28%D0%98_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%29

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличная библиотека iText для создания PDF файлов.
http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: Осталось только запилить JVM на PHP.