# Почему зависает либреофис?

Tags: linux, centos, libre-office

Конвертирую файлы такой командой:

`/usr/bin/soffice --headless document/test.docx --convert-to pdf --outdir pdf`

Но все намертво зависает. Жду жду... Убиваю процесс. Причем что интересно временами это работает. Особенно когда руками команду запускаю. Но когда скриптом пытаюсь обработать много файлов все виснет. :( Скрипт простой:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import os

for file in glob.glob('document/*.*'):
    src = os.path.abspath(file) # это я уже на всякий случай
    dest = os.path.abspath('pdf') # абсолютные пути сделал
    cmd = "/usr/bin/soffice --headless %s --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir %s" % (src, dest)
    print cmd
    os.system(cmd)
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

P.S. Действие происходит на CentOS. Предыстория: нужен конвертер на сайт. Работающих либ на пхп я не нашел. Хочу просто exec-ом вызывать программу-конвертер и конвертировать.

Comment: В том то и дело что не работает. К тому же вдруг кто-то подскажет что-нибудь еще интересное.

Answer (score 0):

Когда скриптом множественно обрабатываете, запускается много процессов конвертации одновременно, возможно железо просто не справляется

Comment: А с какого перепуга они запускаются одновременно? Насколько я понимаю они должны последовательно запускаться. Тут нет асинхронности в коде.

Comment: В коде все поочередно, это бесспорно. Но сама конвертация - процесс не секундный. Ваш код ее запустил, она начала идти, не дожидаясь окончания, ваш код запускает следующую и т.д

Comment: Не думаю. Дальше принтов нет. Видите у меня вывод там стоит? Если бы код пошел дальше не дожидаясь завершения - у меня бы дальше принтом выводило следующие команды, но их нет! Выводит только первую и висит.

Comment: только что случайно наткнулся, можно так попробовать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/237829/Преобразование-doc-в-pdf-на-сайте

Comment: Уже раз 5 эту ссылку видел. Там нет решения.

Comment: Попробуй команду написать так libreoffice --nologo --invisible --convert-to pdf file.doc

Comment: Не, все равно виснет. :( Причем даже когда руками запускаю на том файле на котором оно срабатывало раньше. Теперь вообще че-то сломалось и не пашет ни в какую. :(

Comment: вот прямо сейчас у себя сделал то же самое с doc файлом размером 15Мб, все хорошо отработало

Comment: Я же говорю - оно работало раньше, но сейчас почему-то не работает. Я просто не представляю почему так... Файл меньше 1мб размером.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68694/discussion-between---and-dark-byte).